# Python GPA Calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x

As part of a project I made a GPA calculator. It takes in the class name and letter grade for that class and adds them to a list (eventually I'll add some features that require me to have the grades and classes paired to each other) then adds points according to the grade and then divides by 6 the number of classes I have and gives me a total GPA.

```
        #GPA Calc

#Lists 
classes= []
grades = []

#Collects the data of Class names and Grades in Letter Form
def collect():
    i = 0
    while (i <= 5):
        className = input("Enter Class Name: ")
        classes.append(className)
        i = i +1


    print(classes)
    y = 0
    while (y <=5):
        grade = input("Enter Your Grade For Each Class Listed in Order (Letter Form): ")
        grade = grade.upper()
        grades.append(grade)
        y = y + 1
    calculate()

def calculate():
    total= 0
    for element in grades:
        if element == "A+":
            total = total + 4.0
        elif element == "A":
            total = total + 4.0
        elif element == "A-":
            total = total + 3.7
        elif element == "B+":
            total = total + 3.3
        elif element == "B":
            total = total + 3.0
        elif element == "B-":
            total = total + 2.7
        elif element == "C+":
            total = total + 2.3
        elif element == "C":
            total = total + 2.0
        elif element == "C-":
            total = total + 1.7
        elif element == "D":
            total = total + 1.0
    gpa = total / 6
    print(gpa)


collect()
```

It all works the way it should, but if someone more experienced could tell me a better way to work with the class names and the grade associated and if there is a more efficient way to calculate the grades with some kind of dictionary or some other way, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Avoid global variables

There's no good reason for the variables `classes` and `grades` to be defined and manipulated in global scope.
For example, it would be better to pass `grades` into the `calculate` function as a parameter.

#### Consider a table-driven solution

The long if-else chain is tedious.
You could instead use a dictionary to map the grade notes to scores:

```
score_map = {
    'A': 4,
    'C': 2,
    'C-': 1.7,
    'D': 1,
    # ... and so on
}
total = 0
for grade in grades:
    total += score_map[grade]
```

This approach also makes it easy to use a list-comprehension that's more compact than a for loop:

```
return sum(score_map[grade] for grade in grades) / 6
```

#### Usability

Making the user enter the class names seems rather pointless.
The program simply prints them back, without doing anything interesting with them.

#### Style

The parentheses are redundant here:

> ```
> while (y <= 5):
> ```

Instead of `y = y + 1` you can use the augmented assignment form `y += 1`.

Python has a style guide called [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) with a utility to spot such issues.